# How to style a conditionally rendered ternary operator in a separate css file?

Tags: reactjs, ternary, conditional-rendering

I am tasked with removing all inline css in my project.  It is a React project with sass.  I was able to remove all inline css and put in a separate "styles" directory except this one.  I told my boss we can just leave it as it is minimal and makes the code more readable but he insists on removing it and putting in a separate file in the styles directory.
How would one go about doing this?  Any and all help is appreciated.

****Here is the code**** (this is a snipet from a component file)

```js
               isLoggedIn ? (
                    <span
                        className='share-icon cursor'
                        style={
                            {
                                height: '20px',
                                width: '100px'
                            }
                        }
                    >
                        <img src={shareImage}/>
                    </span>
                ) : (
                    <span
                        className='people-icon cursor'
                        style={
                            {
                                height: '20px',
                                width: '100px'
                            }
                        }
                    >
                        <img src={groupImage}/>
                    </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a class with these height and width values and use it in both cases:

```
 isLoggedIn ? (
                <span
                    className='share-icon cursor whatever-classname-makes-sense'>
                    <img src={shareImage}/>
                </span>
            ) : (
                <span
                    className='people-icon cursor whatever-classname-makes-sense'>
                    <img src={groupImage}/>
                </span>
```

CSS:

```
.whatever-classname-makes-sense {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}
```